# What are .C1 and .C2 Gerber files in Altium 14?

Tags: pcb, altium, gerber

I am currently working on a project and I'm about to get the Gerber files checked by FreeDFM.com. My question is, in my Gerber files, there are a couple that have the extension .C1 and .C2. In FreeDFM.com they want me to specify what these are (Inner copper layers, top layers etc.), but I have no idea what they are.

Any help in determining what these are would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Did you layout the board yourself and generate the Gerbers? Or were they given to you? Do you know how many layers the board is supposed to be?

Comment: Yup! I did the layout and generated the Gerber files of the board myself. The board is just two layers.

Comment: C1 and C2 are probably the top and bottom copper layers respectively. You could download a Gerber viewer to double check. Since the board is two layers, you do not have any inner layers.

Comment: An alternative is importing the files separately on Altium's CAM editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally the mid-layers in Altium are **.G1**, **.G2**, etc. Top and bottom layers are **.GTL** and **.GBL** respectively.

Possibly you're mistaking the G for a C, or possibly the program could be configured to use those extensions (though I don't think the version of Altium we're using has that capability).

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not mistaking G's for C's although I wish I were. These files appear once I export them from Altium!

http://i.imgur.com/ZHIhzaz.png

Comment: They're very small- open them with a text editor and see what's in there.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this also this morning - turned out to be the export from camtastic to gerber setting "Separate Composite layers to individual files" checkbox.  It should NOT be checked:

[image]

To get there, have the Camtastic file open and go to menu File => Export => Gerbers

Note that I had to save my project in AD19 for the changes to work.

Comment: Done!  Look at my original post.  Note that I had to save my project in AD19 for the changes to work.